# Angularjs page initial load very slow

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm pretty new to Angular and my page's initial load is extremely slow. After the initial load the navigation panel, which controls which products to include in the 'ng-repeat' runs perfect.

When I remove the script that begins my Angular JavaScript code it loads perfect again, so it may have something to do with how I coded that.

The first 3 tabs (including their drop-downs) are working. The search engine in the sidebar is incredibly slow too.

**Angular JavaScript**

```
(function (){
    var app = angular.module('craneStore', []);

    app.controller('StoreController', function(){
        this.products = craneStuff;
    });

    app.controller('TabController', function(){
        this.tab = 'featured';

        this.setTab = function(newValue){
            this.tab = newValue;
        };

        this.isSet = function(tabName){
            return this.tab === tabName;
        };
    });

    var craneStuff = [{

           *All my expressions *

    }];
})();
```

I know this alone isn't enough, so here's a link to the area I'm testing this in:

[My Test Area](http://craneshit.com/playground.php)

Comment: Did you even see the network tab in developer console? It is loading bunch of large images from your `craneStuff` object. `76` out of `78` requests is being send to download the images which is almost `5mb`.

Comment: Try moving your <script> tags to the bottom of the page.

Comment: My Network tab isn't showing the images, but that is likely an issue - it's gotta be loading all the images before my Angular tells it not to until the DOM elements are clicked. As for the <script> tags at the bottom - tried that with no luck (moved the angular.min.js and products.js which is where all the expressions are called in)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main culprit is the ENORMOUS images you are sending to the page. Your javascript is waiting for these images to load, which is not unreasonable behavior unless the images are gigantic. Here's an example of one of the images on the site:

http://craneshit.com/images/products/standards/B30-28-10.jpg

Unless you really need to send 3200 pixel images, you should resize them.

Comment: I tried removing these images and loading the page with none, but still slow. I think images are still part of the problem though - I believe it may be loading all my images prior to my ng-repeat restrictions firing. I thought that's what Angular was for (controlling when DOM elements show, hide, populate, etc) but I may be setting something up wrong

Comment: You nailed it I think. I have an element on the page that is set to 'display: none' (the lightbox for the sections). images inside of DOM elements with 'display: none' still load though. So in the end, nothing to do with Angular :\ Good catch, thanks!